# Can we get running js script details in nodejs

Tags: node.js

This query is more related to nodejs(compared to particular os) thats why posting it here.

I have searched for similar problem, but I did not get any satisfactory results.

I want to know that **Is there any way that we can figure out the JS Script(name, location) node is running currently?**

e.g.
If I am running a nodejs webserver on port 3000, and if I forget the original script location, or somebody else start using my computer.
So, **is it possible using nodejs to get the location of this script.**

Answer (score 2):

Try the global variable `__filename`, as detailed [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html).

Comment: But question is about how externally we can know the script details, for your solution I will need to modify existing script add __filename there which I can not do if I dont know which script is being executed.